# My "script" doesnt work on chrome but does on firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, jquery-animate

I have a few lines of code wich works fine on Firefox but doesn't work on Chrome

HTML

```
<div id="container" >
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="wat" onmouseenter="showDiv(this)" onmouseleave="removeDiv(this)">      
        <div id="wathover">
            <div id="watpopup">Dit is een test. Klik <a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">hier</a> voor meer informatie.           

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      

    <div id="hoe"></div>
    <div id="waarom"></div>
    <div id="wanneer"></div>
    <div id="voorbeeldbox1"></div>
    <div id="voorbeeldbox2"></div>
    <div id="voorbeeldbox3"></div>
    <div id="wie"></div>
    <div id="waar"></div>
</div>
```

The code in the file javascript.

```
    function showDiv(parent){
    var child = $(parent).find("div").attr("id");   
     $('#'+child).animate({
        height:'show'
     },100);
}   

function removeDiv(parent){ 
    var child = $(parent).find("div").attr("id");   
     $('#'+child).animate({
        height:'hide'
     },100);    
}
```

CSS

```
    body {
    margin:0px;
    background-color: black;
}

#container{
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: black;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 675px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#logo{
    margin-left: 30px;  
    width: 600px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: url('../afbeeldingen/logoklein.png');
}

/* Wat blok*/

#wat {
    display: block;
    background-image: url('../afbeeldingen/wat.png');
    background-color: gray;
    width: 600px;
    height: 340px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
    position: relative; 
}

#wathover {
    display: none;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    width: 600px;
    height: 150px;
    float: right;   
    margin-top: 190px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;    
}

#watpopup {
    margin-left: 75px;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}

#watinside {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;  
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Georgia; 
    overflow: auto; 
}

.wat_text {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

/* Hoe blok*/

#hoe {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 380px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 670px;
    margin-top: -340px;
}

/* waarom blok*/

#waarom {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 380px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 670px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* wanneer blok*/

#wanneer {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 380px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 670px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* voorbeeldbox1 blok*/

#voorbeeldbox1 {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 325px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* voorbeeldbox2 blok*/

#voorbeeldbox2 {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 325px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 388px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

/* voorbeeldbox3 blok*/

#voorbeeldbox3 {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 325px;
    height: 150px   ;
    margin-left: 725px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

/* wie blok*/

#wie {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 495px;
    height: 75px    ;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* waar blok*/

#waar {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 495px;
    height: 75px    ;
    margin-left: 555px;
    margin-top: -75px;  
}
```

It should animate a div from the bottom in de biggest div when mouse enters. And animate the div back to not visable when the mouse leaves Wich it does on firefox but not on chrome. Can anyone help me? Language is dutch for the ones who are interested!

EDIT: I have changed it to this:

HTML:

```
    <head>
<title>Double You Media</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/main.css' />
<script src="javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery.lightbox_me.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#wat").hover(function(){$('#wathover').stop().animate({height:'show'},100);}, function(){$('#wathover').stop().animate({height:'hide'},100);});
    $("#hoe").hover(function(){$('#hoehover').stop().animate({height:'show'},100);}, function(){$('#hoehover').stop().animate({height:'hide'},100);});
    $("#waarom").hover(function(){$('#waaromhover').stop().animate({height:'show'},100);}, function(){$('#waaromhover').stop().animate({height:'hide'},100);});
    $("#wanneer").hover(function(){$('#wanneerhover').stop().animate({height:'show'},100);}, function(){$('#wanneerhover').stop().animate({height:'hide'},100);});
    $("#voorbeeldbox1").hover(function(){$('#voorbeeldbox1hover').stop().animate({height:'show'},100);}, function(){$('#voorbeeldbox1hover').stop().animate({height:'hide'},100);});
    $("#voorbeeldbox2").hover(function(){$('#voorbeeldbox2hover').stop().animate({height:'show'},100);}, function(){$('#voorbeeldbox2hover').stop().animate({height:'hide'},100);});
    $("#voorbeeldbox3").hover(function(){$('#voorbeeldbox3hover').stop().animate({height:'show'},100);}, function(){$('#voorbeeldbox3hover').stop().animate({height:'hide'},100);});
    $("#wie").hover(function(){$('#wiehover').stop().animate({height:'show'},100);}, function(){$('#wiehover').stop().animate({height:'hide'},100);});
    $("#waar").hover(function(){$('#waarhover').stop().animate({height:'show'},100);}, function(){$('#waarhover').stop().animate({height:'hide'},100);});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>  

    <div id="container" >
        <div id="logo"></div>

        <div id="wat">      
            <div id="wathover">
                <div id="watpopup">Dit is een test. Klik <a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">hier</a> voor meer informatie.           
                    <div id="watinside">
                        <p class="wat_text"><br><br>Hier <br><br>kan <br><br>u nog veel<br><br> meer lezen over <br><br>het onderwerp <br><br>wat u wilt aanbieden</p>                      
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div id="hoe">
            <div id="hoehover">
                <div id="hoepopup">Dit is een test. Klik <a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">hier</a> voor meer informatie.           
                    <div id="hoeinside">
                        <p class="hoe_text"><br><br>Hier <br><br>kan <br><br>u nog veel<br><br> meer lezen over <br><br>het onderwerp <br><br>wat u wilt aanbieden</p>                      
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="waarom">
            <div id="waaromhover">
                <div id="waarompopup">Dit is een test. Klik <a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">hier</a> voor meer informatie.            
                    <div id="waarominside">
                        <p class="waarom_text"><br><br>Hier <br><br>kan <br><br>u nog veel<br><br> meer lezen over <br><br>het onderwerp <br><br>wat u wilt aanbieden</p>                       
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div id="wanneer">
            <div id="wanneerhover">
                <div id="wanneerpopup">Dit is een test. Klik <a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">hier</a> voor meer informatie.           
                    <div id="wanneerinside">
                        <p class="wanneer_text"><br><br>Hier <br><br>kan <br><br>u nog veel<br><br> meer lezen over <br><br>het onderwerp <br><br>wat u wilt aanbieden</p>                      
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div id="voorbeeldbox1">
            <div id="voorbeeldbox1hover">
                <div id="voorbeeldbox1popup">Dit is een test. Klik <a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">hier</a> voor meer informatie.         
                    <div id="voorbeeldbox1inside">
                        <p class="voorbeeldbox1_text"><br><br>Hier <br><br>kan <br><br>u nog veel<br><br> meer lezen over <br><br>het onderwerp <br><br>wat u wilt aanbieden</p>                        
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div id="voorbeeldbox2">
            <div id="voorbeeldbox2hover">
                <div id="voorbeeldbox2popup">Dit is een test. Klik <a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">hier</a> voor meer informatie.         
                    <div id="voorbeeldbox2inside">
                        <p class="voorbeeldbox2_text"><br><br>Hier <br><br>kan <br><br>u nog veel<br><br> meer lezen over <br><br>het onderwerp <br><br>wat u wilt aanbieden</p>                        
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div id="voorbeeldbox3">
            <div id="voorbeeldbox3hover">
                <div id="voorbeeldbox3popup">Dit is een test. Klik <a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">hier</a> voor meer informatie.         
                    <div id="voorbeeldbox3inside">
                        <p class="voorbeeldbox3_text"><br><br>Hier <br><br>kan <br><br>u nog veel<br><br> meer lezen over <br><br>het onderwerp <br><br>wat u wilt aanbieden</p>                        
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div id="wie">
            <div id="wiehover">
                <div id="wiepopup">Dit is een test. Klik <a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">hier</a> voor meer informatie.           
                    <div id="wieinside">
                        <p class="wie_text"><br><br>Hier <br><br>kan <br><br>u nog veel<br><br> meer lezen over <br><br>het onderwerp <br><br>wat u wilt aanbieden</p>                      
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div id="waar">
            <div id="waarhover">
                <div id="waarpopup">Dit is een test. Klik <a href="#" onclick="popup(this)">hier</a> voor meer informatie.          
                    <div id="waarinside">
                        <p class="waar_text"><br><br>Hier <br><br>kan <br><br>u nog veel<br><br> meer lezen over <br><br>het onderwerp <br><br>wat u wilt aanbieden</p>                     
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    background-color: black;
}

#container{
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: black;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 675px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#logo{
    margin-left: 30px;  
    width: 600px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: url('../afbeeldingen/logoklein.png');
}

/* Wat blok*/

#wat {
    display: block;
    background-image: url('../afbeeldingen/wat.png');
    background-color: gray;
    width: 600px;
    height: 340px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
    position: relative; 
}

#wathover {
    display: none;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    width: 600px;
    height: 150px;
    float: right;   
    margin-top: 190px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;    
}

#watpopup {
    margin-left: 75px;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}

#watinside {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;  
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Georgia; 
    overflow: auto; 
}

.wat_text {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

/* Hoe blok*/

#hoe {  
    width: 380px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 670px;
    margin-top: -340px;
    background-image: url('../afbeeldingen/hoe.png');
}

#hoehover {
    display: none;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    width: 380px;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1000; left: 1000;    
}

#hoepopup {
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#hoeinside {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;  
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Georgia; 
    overflow: auto; 
}

.hoe_text {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

/* waarom blok*/

#waarom {
    background-image: url('../afbeeldingen/waarom.png');
    width: 380px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 670px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#waaromhover {
    display: none;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    width: 380px;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1000; left: 1000;    
}

#waarompopup {
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#waarominside {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;  
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Georgia; 
    overflow: auto; 
}

.waarom_text {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

/* wanneer blok*/

#wanneer {
    background-image: url('../afbeeldingen/wanneer.png');
    width: 380px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 670px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#wanneerhover {
    display: none;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    width: 380px;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1000; left: 1000;    
}

#wanneerpopup {
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#wanneerinside {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;  
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Georgia; 
    overflow: auto; 
}

.wanneer_text {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

/* voorbeeldbox1 blok*/

#voorbeeldbox1 {
    background-image: url('../afbeeldingen/product1.png');
    width: 325px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#voorbeeldbox1hover {
    display: none;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    width: 325px;
    height: 150px;
    float: right;   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1000; left: 1000;    
}

#voorbeeldbox1popup {
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#voorbeeldbox1inside {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;  
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Georgia; 
    overflow: auto; 
}

.voorbeeldbox1_text {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}


/* voorbeeldbox2 blok*/

#voorbeeldbox2 {
    background-image: url('../afbeeldingen/product2.png');
    width: 325px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 388px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

#voorbeeldbox2hover {
    display: none;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    width: 325px;
    height: 150px;
    float: right;   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1000; left: 1000;    
}

#voorbeeldbox2popup {
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#voorbeeldbox2inside {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;  
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Georgia; 
    overflow: auto; 
}

.voorbeeldbox2_text {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

/* voorbeeldbox3 blok*/

#voorbeeldbox3 {
    background-image: url('../afbeeldingen/product3.png');
    width: 325px;
    height: 150px   ;
    margin-left: 725px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

#voorbeeldbox3hover {
    display: none;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    width: 325px;
    height: 150px;
    float: right;   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1000; left: 1000;    
}

#voorbeeldbox3popup {
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#voorbeeldbox3inside {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;  
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Georgia; 
    overflow: auto; 
}

.voorbeeldbox3_text {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

/* wie blok*/

#wie {
    background-image: url('../afbeeldingen/wie.png');
    width: 495px;
    height: 75px    ;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#wiehover {
    display: none;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    width: 495px;
    height: 75px;
    float: right;   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1000; left: 1000;    
}

#wiepopup {
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#wieinside {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;  
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Georgia; 
    overflow: auto; 
}

.wie_text {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

/* waar blok*/

#waar {
    background-image: url('../afbeeldingen/waar.png');
    width: 495px;
    height: 75px    ;
    margin-left: 555px;
    margin-top: -75px;  
}

#waarhover {
    display: none;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    width: 495px;
    height: 75px;
    float: right;   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1000; left: 1000;    
}

#waarpopup {
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#waarinside {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;  
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Georgia; 
    overflow: auto; 
}

.waar_text {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

You can see the site on www.dymedia.nl/doubleyoumedia As you can see it works now. But when you hover a lot of times its starts to flip out. Or you see the half of the animated divs, or you see a line or you don't see them at all. Any thoughts what causes this? And as you can see the big block has the div comming from the bottom. I want to have that on the other divs aswell but i have no clue how to get that to work. Help would be apriciated.

Comment: [Chrome doesn't support `mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: As @user2000008 said. The closest would be `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Comment: Ok but whit the mouseover and mouseout it just flips out. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Rhyono ive made some changes. Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder why you would ever need two jqueries on the same page.